# My NodeJs App is automatically restarting between 2 and 3 hours

Tags: node.js, namecheap

I hosted my nodejs app on Namecheap shared hosting. My app has some functions with big `setInterval`s that runs once every 8 hour and every 24 hour. For unknown reasons my production nodejs app is restarting  some time between every 2 and 3 hours. That is why my `setInterval`s functions are never executed. I used `try... catch...` everywhere to prevent my app from crashing, so there are no errors that cause to be restarted. I am wondering why my app is restarted some time between every 2 and 3 hours. Any suggestions please!

Comment: Only enough details here for us to guess. Do you have any logs? Could it be a memory issue?

Comment: @Codebling there are only errors that arre already catched by `try... catch...` block in `stdeer.log`. But how can I check if it is a memory erorr? Do you mean RAM?

Comment: There's no explanation for the exit in your run logs? From whatever is running your Node.js process? And yes I mean perhaps you are hitting your memory ("RAM") limit

Comment: namecheap automatically restarts your node apps. it restarts mine too about every 30 minutes